# Should I use useState for value when creating a form in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';

 export default function Page() {
   const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.currentTarget.email.value);
     console.log(e.currentTarget.password.value);
   };
   return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input type="text" name="email" />
       <input type="password" name="password" />
       <button type="submit">login</button>
     </form>
   );
 }

 /////////////////////////////////
export default function Page() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The code above does not use useState, while the code below uses useState to specify the value and onChange to specify the value. What is the difference between the two and which is the more correct code? I have only written the code below so far, but I have seen some code that looks like the code above. Please tell me the difference between the two and which is the more correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is; Should I use Controlled or uncontrolled state.

This is the name of the React terminology.

Both code examples are absolutely fine and pretty clean, the question to ask yourself is; Do I want to do anything with the values pre or post submit?

If no then you can find the values as you are doing from the event and pass them on. Or you can Control the Input field and store said state locally and access it on to the submit.

I hope this elaborates on your question, please feel free to ask a follow-up if anything is still unclear.